# Can't create more than two follow-up intents for a given intent in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

For some reason, I cannot create more than two follow-up intents for any given parent intent in dialogflow.  I used to be able to do that.  Now, after I've created two, when I click "Add follow-up intent", it gives me the option for what type, and when I click on the type I want (ie. custom), nothing happens.  Not sure what is going on.  I'm using dialogflow V2.

Side question: is this capability present in V3?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you update your question to include screen shots of what you're trying to do and what isn't working? (And I'm not aware of an announced or released v3)

Comment: There's really nothing to take a screenshot of.  You go into the list of intents, click "Add follow-up intent" for one of them to create a follow-up intent, then repeat again, and then repeat again but this time no follow-up intent gets created.

Comment: Same here. Although I couldn't find about custom follow-up limitation anywhere in doc apparently it is limited to two. However, you can add predefined follow-up and change the name and content according to your need.